# How do you access WhatsApp "Databases" folder from the PC?

Tags: android, desktop-computer, whatsapp

Bought new LG 4 and even though I am downloading apps I cannot find their respective folders when I hook my LG to the PC (including WhatsApp). Even when I search for default stuff like "google" i cannot find a thing.

Is there a special way to access files in an android phone from PC? I need to copy my manual conversation backup into the Databases folder.

Comment: The apps themselves are not available. Only their settings (if saved in files rather than dB's) are visible. That is a feature of the OS. All of the mobile OSes made in the last 5-6 years are like that..

Comment: @kodyBrown its a problem because I need to manually copy a backup of WhatsApp conversation history to the DB file in the app, which was available for browsing in my Galaxy S3. Any workaround?

Comment: I don't know of a workaround. I would update your question to specifically ask about WhatsApp. You might get more traction.

Comment: Seems a little bit weird to me. If you can't access those folders when you're on your pc then just copy your backups to the root directory of the phone. Use a File-Manager on your LG G4 to copy the backups to the Whatsapp Directory. But usually you should be able to copy your backup to this folder from a pc. Make sure your LG G4 is set to USB-Data mode - not 'Charge only'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android only allows you access to a specific folder. This is to ensure you don't break anything. The folder you have access to is "/storage/emulated/0" (at least on a Samsung Galaxy running 5.1.1).

In order for you to be access the root directory you must root your phone, it is usually a 10-15 minute process depending on a lot of factors.

Before rooting you should always create a backup. After that you must enable USB Debugging in Developer Options. You can do this by going to "Settings>About Phone" and then tapping on the build number several times. Then navigate to "Settings>Developer Options" and enable "USB Debugging".

That's wasn't so hard was it? Well it's about to. Follow this guide to unlock your bootloader: http://www.android.gs/unlock-lg-g4-bootloader/

Then install a custom recovery by following this guide: http://www.android.gs/install-twrp-recovery-on-lg-g4/

Once you have found the patience and courage to go through all that to get root access you must understand that you yet do not have root access YET.

If your ready to do the actual rooting process follow these steps:

1. Go to https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip?retrieve_file=1 (either on your computer or phone) and download the SuperSU file

Follow steps 2 and 3 ONLY if you downloaded it on your computer. Otherwise skip to step 4.

2. Connect your LG G4 to your computer using the USB cord.
3. Transfer the file you downloaded on your computer to your phone and disconnect the USB cord.
4. Turn off your phone and wait a few seconds
5. Enter recovery mode, if you do not know how follow this guide: http://www.android.gs/enter-recovery-mode-lg-g4/
6. Go to install, select the root exploit, and resume the flashing process.
7. After its done reboot your phone through an option you will find in the main menu.

That's it, your done. Now think about what you had to go through and if it was worth all the errors you probably faced trying to do so if this is your first time.

If you get stuck in a boot loop or if anything goes wrong, go to recovery and select “wipe data factory reset” and “wipe cache partition." If you did not have a backup then RIP DATA. Once that's done you can reboot your phone as new and attempt to root again.

Comment: Why should rooting be necessary here? He does not want to access system partition. Furthermore rooting might void his warranty. Your answer targets a question like "How do I root my LG G4?" - but this is not the case here

Comment: Images, like all media and messages received through WhatsApp are stored locally. They're stored into /data/data/com.whatsapp/ (I believe) which requires root access.

Comment: The whatsapp database is located in sdcard0/WhatsApp/Databases and can be accessed without root privileges.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data this supports my answer

Comment: Yeah well no. This answer might backup certain aspects of your answer but to access the WhatsApp Databases you don't need root. Simple as that. The files are on the data partition - every user can access it without root.

Comment: Well I just realized that I shouldn't be debating since I never used WhatsApp before :P some websites say that you don't need root and some say that you do.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Windows 10 and a new LG X Screen with Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow with no SD card attached:
Some folders where visible on the mobile phones file manager but where not visible in Windows Explorer after connecting the phone to the PC with USB for file transfer.

Beside the Internal Storage folder "Interner Speicher/WhatsApp/Databases" also some other folders where missing. So this is not a WhatsApp-specific problem. Since this new mobile phone has been running for about 10 days without reboot/power off since initial set up, I assumed a kind of caching problem in the form of a missing "flush"-command.

The missing folders where visible on the USB-connected PC after I did ...

1. unlink the USB-connection
2. shut down and restart the phone
3. delete the cached files via

   - en: "Settings > General > Storage & USB > Cached data"
   - de: "Einstellungen > Allgemein > Speicherplatz & USB > Zwischengespeicherte Daten"

I don't know for sure if the reboot alone whould have been sufficient.

This issue seems to correspond with [Issue #38282: Android MTP support does not show recent files until the device is rebooted](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282) on Google-Code for Android.

Comment: I can confirm that restarting the phone is sufficient.